# convert bib file to \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear

Tags: latex

I have a reference file (bib file) I want to convert it as

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Allen C.W.}{1973}] {b1} Allen C.W., 1973,
Astrophysical quantities, ${3^{rd}}$ ed. (Athlone Press, London)

when I use

```
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{bibfile}
```

Output ppl file as

\bibitem[Allen, 1973]{allen1973astrophysical}
Allen, C.~W. (1973).

Comment: This seems to be a bibliography style similar to `jneurosci` and `namedplus`

Comment: Or natbib with together with the `newapa` style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining `natbib` with the `newapa` style gives something similar:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{1973asqu.book.....A,
   author = {{Allen}, C.~W.},
    title = "{Astrophysical quantities}",
 keywords = {ASTROPHYSICS, ASTRONOMICAL CONSTANTS, TABLES, HANDBOOKS},
booktitle = {London: University of London, Athlone Press, |c1973, 3rd ed.},
     year = 1973,
   adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1973asqu.book.....A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{1973asqu.book.....A}

\bibliographystyle{newapa}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Resulting .bbl file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{{Allen}}{{Allen}}{1973}]{1973asqu.book.....A}
{Allen}, C.~W. (1973).
\newblock {\em {Astrophysical quantities}}.

\end{thebibliography}
```